# O365 Unified Client Library - Authentication Failed "Stream does not support seeking."

Tags: office365, azure-mobile-services

I've finally got my app working with Azure AD Authentication through Azure App Services/Mobile Apps.

I'm now looking to use the Unified API (Microsoft.Graph) to access some user files.

I wish there was a way I could use the token I already retrieved from Mobile Services, but it seems to be asking the user to login again, not really a problem at the moment though.

The problem lies when trying to authenticate:

```
private static async Task<string> TryTokenHelperAsync(AuthenticationContext context, string resourceId)
    {

        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext =
                 new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", false);
        AuthenticationResult userAuthnResult =
                 await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                     resourceId,
                     ClientID,
                     redirectUri,
                     PromptBehavior.Always
                 );
        var TokenForUser = userAuthnResult.AccessToken;
        return TokenForUser;
    }
```

The AuthenticationResult comes back with the following properties:
Error: "authentication_failed"
ErrorMessage: "Stream does not support seeking."
Status: "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationStatus.ClientError"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your app registration and select the permission scopes the app requires and get a token for resource=https://graph.microsoft.com to be able to use that token to call the Office365 unified API. 
More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/get-started-with-office-365-unified-api